# Busca com expressões regulares

Tags: php

Ola gostaria da ajuda de vocês com o seguinte problema, que possuo nesse código.

```
    function verificarParametro($loopurl,$urlHost) {
if (preg_match("/(\W|^){$urlHost}(\W|$)/i", $loopurl))
    return true;
    else
    return false;
```

Ele faz uma verificação da url pegando o parâmetro posto em `$urlHost` e verificando em `$loopurl` , se o valor existir da verdadeiro, caso contrario da falso.

Agora eis o meu problema, necessito que faça uma verificação completa do inicio ao fim do parâmetro que foi especificado no campo `$urlHost`, mesmo que ela tenha qualquer caracteres especiais ou qualquer outro tipo de parâmetro, como por exemplo `/*+-!|?\:` etc.

Por exemplo, se eu colocar para buscar esse o parâmetro abaixo, ira dar erro de linha.

```
if (verificarParametroA('https://drive.google.com/file/d/abcdfghiglmnopqrstuvxz/
', 'drive.google.com/file/d/')) {

    echo 'Sim'; }
```

Comment: Utilize preg_quote($urlHost,'/') para escapar a URL. Mas acho que você está usando ER para algo que não precisa, um strpos() do php resolveria!

Comment: Note que o uso de strpos e stripos também irão falhar se tiver algo assim `verificarParametroA('https://foo.com?u=http://bar.com', 'bar.com')`, sugiro o `parse_url`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/305297/3635 - fora que o uso do `strpos` com `(bool)` ali na outra resposta é totalmente equivacado, já que o retorno `0` causaria `false`, quando na verdade `0` significa que encontrou desde o primeiro caractere em strpos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao passar o parametro diretamente na expressão irá causar problemas:

```
"/(\W|^){$urlHost}(\W|$)/i"
```

Você deve escapar os caracteres com `preg_quote` ([como citado pelo @W.Faustino com o delimitador `/`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305262/busca-com-express%C3%B5es-regulares/305297#comment619632_305262)), outra coisa é que provavelmente a regex deveria ser:

```
/^(\W|){$urlHost}(\W|$)/i
```

Pois se o sinal `^` não estiver no começo uma url assim poderia retornar TRUE:

```
verificarParametroA('https://foo.com?u=http://bar.com', 'bar.com')
```

> **Note** que o uso de **`strpos`** e **`stripos`** também irão falhar

Deve ficar assim (realmente não é necessário um if e else neste caso):

```
function verificarParametro($loopurl, $urlHost) {
    $urlHost = preg_quote($urlHost, '/');
    return !!preg_match("/^(\W|){$urlHost}(\W|$)/i", $loopurl);
}
```

No entanto eu recomendo mesmo que use a função `parse_url`, ela vai extrair os dados necessários e assim você vai poder fazer uma checagem mais precisa assim:

```
function verificarParametro($loopurl, $urlHost)
{
    $host = parse_url($loopurl, PHP_URL_HOST);
    return strcasecmp($host, $urlHost) == 0;
}
```

> **Nota:** usei `strcasecmp` para comparar se ambas strings são iguais independente em case-insenstive

Answer (score 1):

Se o $loopurl precisa estar contido exatamente igual dentro do $urlHost pode ser usado [strpos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php). Exemplo:

```
function verificarParametro($loopurl, $urlHost)
{
    return (bool) strpos('https://drive.google.com/file/d/abcdfghiglmnopqrstuvxz/', $loopurl);
}
```

Comment: Não seria `return strpos(...) !== false;` ?

Comment: Hm, verdade esqueci que ele precisa de um valor booleano. Editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigada, achou o valor perfeitamente.